# ExtJS not rendering

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS code that I grabbed from [Sencha](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.chart.series.CandleStick.html#properties) and I'm trying to run it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sgokynn/1/) and make a few edits to see how it changes.

But the graph is not showing at all.

Any idea how to render the graph?

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'cartesian',
        store: {
            fields: ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'],
            data: [{
                    'time': new Date('Jan 1 2010').getTime(),
                    'open': 600,
                    'high': 614,
                    'low': 578,
                    'close': 590
                },
                {
                    'time': new Date('Jan 2 2010').getTime(),
                    'open': 590,
                    'high': 609,
                    'low': 580,
                    'close': 580
                },
                {
                    'time': new Date('Jan 3 2010').getTime(),
                    'open': 580,
                    'high': 602,
                    'low': 578,
                    'close': 602
                },
                {
                    'time': new Date('Jan 4 2010').getTime(),
                    'open': 602,
                    'high': 614,
                    'low': 586,
                    'close': 586
                },
                {
                    'time': new Date('Jan 5 2010').getTime(),
                    'open': 586,
                    'high': 602,
                    'low': 565,
                    'close': 565
                }
            ]
        },
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'],
            title: {
                text: 'Sample Values',
                fontSize: 15
            },
            grid: true,
            minimum: 560,
            maximum: 640
        }, {
            type: 'time',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['time'],
            fromDate: new Date('Dec 31 2009'),
            toDate: new Date('Jan 6 2010'),
            title: {
                text: 'Sample Values',
                fontSize: 15
            },
            style: {
                axisLine: false
            }
        }],
        series: {
            type: 'candlestick',
            xField: 'time',
            openField: 'open',
            highField: 'high',
            lowField: 'low',
            closeField: 'close',
            style: {
                dropStyle: {
                    fill: 'rgb(237, 123, 43)',
                    stroke: 'rgb(237, 123, 43)'
                },
                raiseStyle: {
                    fill: 'rgb(55, 153, 19)',
                    stroke: 'rgb(55, 153, 19)'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I also tried to add a div and have it rendered to it but it doesn't work

```
<div id = "frm"></div>

/*...*/

renderTo : 'frm'
```

I'm not totally sure if the reason for that is because of the **ExtJS** version but based on Sencha documentation, candlestick charts `Ext.chart.series.CandleStick` have been introduced in version **5.0.0** of ExtJS.

Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Grab the code from [here (extjs 6.5)](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.chart.series.CandleStick.html) and add it to a [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) or alter the code inside the docs example.

Answer (score 2):

Before to use any chart in [ExtJS 5.0.0](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/index.html), you need to requires `sencha-charts` in your `app.json` file without include you can't resolve `error`. There is no directly `chart gpl` library like [ExtJS 5.0.1 sencha-charts-debug](https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/5.0.1/packages/sencha-charts/build/sencha-charts-debug.js).

For more details you can refer this [sencha forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289329-Charting-with-Ext-JS-5).

Here is `ExtJS 5.0.1`  **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/njdhv10/25aahwfg/)** you can check here for chart worked well because of external gpl chart library is available here.

I hope with help this answer you will resolve your issue in your working code.